# How to display product attributes in WooCommerce and quantity in the back end all products page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want see attributes in the back end on the all products page.
and can it shows the quanity vs in stock out of stock?

many plugins tried so far none suitable

Comment: With functionalities like that you are better off writing your own PHP, this allows you to customize it to your liking and also keep your site speed up. See @the_gujarati's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about any plugin for these kind of functionality. But, I've created this functionality. Let me share the details with you.

Add following snippets of code to your active child-theme's functions.php file.

Below displayed snippets will add new columns to All Products page's Product Table. i.e.   Stock Quantity and Color. Here Color is my product's attribute.

```
 add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'admin_products_column', 9999 );
     
    function admin_products_column( $columns ){
       $columns['stock_quantity'] = 'Stock Quantity'; // Stock
       $columns['color'] = 'Color';  // Attribute
       return $columns;
    }
```

Now we need to bring the data in these columns, So for the Stock Quantity use below mentioned code snippets.

```
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'admin_products_stock_column_content', 10, 2 );
 
function admin_products_stock_column_content( $column, $product_id ){
    if ( $column == 'stock_quantity' ) { // condition to check stock qty. column.
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
      echo $product->get_stock_quantity();
    }
}
```

To get data in color attribute column use below mentioned code snippets.

```
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'admin_products_attribute_color_column_content', 10, 2 );
 
function admin_products_attribute_color_column_content( $column, $product_id ){
    if ( $column == 'color' ) {  // condition to check color attribute column
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
      echo $product->get_attribute('pa_color'); // 'pa_color' is Slug of Color Attribute.
    }
}
```

Final result will look like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qa1X.png).